# Identify arabic characters in string

Tags: regex, r

In a dataframe, I have a character variable that has elements including latin characters or arabic characters or both:

```
a <- data.frame(text=c('ناطرريننهمم ع نااارررر', 
               'blah blah blah', 
               'ناطيننهمم ع ناارر blah blah'))
```

I need to create an additional variable in the data frame which is `TRUE` if there is at least 1 arabic character in the corresponding `a$text`. I have tried many `regex` and `Sys.setlocale()` setups but couldn't find any solution so far. For example:

```
a$test[i] <- grepl('[\\s\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]', 
                   a$text[i], perl=TRUE)
```

but it always outputs `FALSE`.

Current locale is set to:

```
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Why `\s` is included?

Comment: You may wish to include other character ranges for rarer Arabic letters.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode and http://www.unicode.org/charts/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter :

```
sapply(a$text, function(texte) {
  grepl("[\\s\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]", texte)
})
```

you get

```
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `grepl` is already vectorised, so you don't need `sapply`. This will suffice: `grepl("[\\s\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]", a$text)`. Also, is there a reason why `grepl("[\u0600-\u06FF]", a$text)` isn't appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder ! Actually, I normally use grepl without sapply, I don't know why I didn't this time !! As for your question, I just used the symbols put in the question without checking what they code so I really don't know, @user3635057 probably does though.

Comment: `grepl("[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]", x, perl=FALSE)` works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this for matching other language character.

```
\S*
```

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/mG6sS6/1